# Keep grid cell stickied until adjacent content is scrolled past

Tags: html, css, css-grid, sticky

I'm trying to create a web page using a grid, and I want a column on the left to be stickied at the top of the page when a row is being scrolled past, and then unstickied when the other content in the row goes off screen.

So far all I've done is create two divs for a row, and set the left one to have `position: sticky` and `top: 0`, so that when the row is being scrolled by, the div on the left stays at the top. This works for one row, but when I add another row to the grid both divs stay attached to the top of the screen.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25vw 75vw;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: 10px solid lightgray;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 70vw;
  gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar">
     <h1>I want this div to be attached to the top of the screen while the row next to it is being scrolled through</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
     <h1>There is a lot of content here</h1>
     <h1>Stretching the entire height of the screen</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
     <h1>But when this row reaches the top, this overlaps with the first sidebar</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
     <h1>There is a lot of content here</h1>
     <h1>Stretching the entire height of the screen</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

The two `sidebar` divs will eventually overlap, and I want one to "detach" from the top of the screen when it gets to this point. Is there a way to do this in pure CSS, or do I have to use Javascript?

Comment: When I turn your comment into a snippet, I cannot see the behaviour you are describing. Please edit your question to include a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285) which replicates the scenario you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you need to separate `.sidebar`. For example, wrap them in a `section` (or `div`):

```css
.sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: 10px solid lightgray;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  gap: 2em;
  min-height: 600px; /* just for example */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h1>I want this div to be attached to the top of the screen while the row next to it is being scrolled through</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>There is a lot of content here</div>
    <div>Stretching the entire height of the screen</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h1>But when this row reaches the top, this overlaps with the first sidebar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>There is a lot of content here</div>
    <div>Stretching the entire height of the screen</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign a background color and fixed height to your sidebar.  It's nothing elegant but it gets the job done.

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25vw 75vw;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: 10px solid lightgray;
  background-color: white;
  height: 120px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 70vw;
  gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar">
     <h1>I want this div to be attached to the top of the screen while the row next to it is being scrolled through</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
     <h1>There is a lot of content here</h1>
     <h1>Stretching the entire height of the screen</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
     <h1>But when this row reaches the top, this overlaps with the first sidebar</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
     <h1>There is a lot of content here</h1>
     <h1>Stretching the entire height of the screen</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```